# JOptionPane showInputDialog position

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

How can I specify the position of a JOptionPane. Can anyone make a class that extends JOptionPane.showInputDialog that also takes in an x,y position?

Comment: I don't think this is possible.

Comment: Why is the the default position relative to the parent component not acceptable?

Comment: +1, the question added something to my knowledge today :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [JOptionPane's setLocation(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setLocation%28int,%20int%29) method. OR Instead of using `JOptionPane` you can extends a [JDialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html), and then specify it's location on the screen.

Here is one working code sample as adviced by @HovercraftFullOfEels , just this example will help you to get input from the user as you asked for :

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class OptionPaneLocation 
{   
    private void createAndDisplayGUI()
    {       
        JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane("Its me"
                                    , JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE
                                    , JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION
                                    , null, null, "Please ENTER your NAME here");
        optionPane.setWantsInput(true);             
        JDialog dialog = optionPane.createDialog(null, "TEST");
        dialog.setLocation(10, 20);
        dialog.setVisible(true);
        System.out.println(optionPane.getInputValue());
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new OptionPaneLocation().createAndDisplayGUI();
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(runnable);
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't the JDialog have nothing in it by default?

Comment: Yeah, true, but it can give functionality equivalent to `JOptionPane` or else you can use `setLocation(...)` method on the instance of `JOptionPane` as specified in my answer.

Comment: @Downvoter: Care to share your wisdom, on the topic, for the downvote. Will highly appreciate much, for learning somethingy new, if there is somethingy wrong, in my explanation :-)

Answer (score 5):

A JOptionPane can be easily turned into a JDialog (check out the [JOptionPane API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) and it will show you how with example). Then you can set the position of the created JDialog.

e.g., from the documentation:

```
 JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane(arguments);
 pane.set.Xxxx(...); // Configure
 JDialog dialog = pane.createDialog(parentComponent, title);
 dialog.setLocation(....);  // added!
 dialog.setModal(....);  // added! Do you want it modal or not?
 // ....
 dialog.setVisible(true);
```