# How to set the location of "JOptionPane.showMessageDialog"

Tags: java, swing, layout, position

I want to make `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog` message appear

- Any place in the screen.
- Relative to JFrame. (not at the centre of the JFrame)

For example this will display the message at the centre of the JFrame provided as argument `thisFrame`

```
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(thisFrame, "Your message.");
```

And this will display the message at the centre of the screen irrelative to any JFrame.

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your message.");
```

- what I want is to set the location of the message any place I want
- what I want is to set the location of the message relative to the JFrame (not at the centre of the JFrame)

How?

Comment: Is my question illegal/invalid in terms of GUI doctrine?! @AndrewThompson

Comment: Note that `JOptionPane` can use ***any*** `Component` as parent.  That means, it can be relatice to the forame, any component inside it, any component any in/any floating window (tool-bar, `JWindow`, `JDialog`) that is on-screen) or of course, `null` (center of screen).

Comment: This [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9807890/1057230) might be of some interest to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class CustomDialog extends JDialog {
    private JPanel myPanel = null;
    private JButton yesButton = null;
    private JButton noButton = null;

    public CustomDialog(JFrame frame, boolean modal, String myMessage) {
    super(frame, modal);
    myPanel = new JPanel();
    getContentPane().add(myPanel);
    myPanel.add(new JLabel(myMessage));
    yesButton = new JButton("Yes");
    myPanel.add(yesButton);
    noButton = new JButton("No");
    myPanel.add(noButton);
    pack();
    //setLocationRelativeTo(frame);
    setLocation(200, 200); // <--
    setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats not the answer to the question.

Comment: @UNIQUEorn I think it is.

Comment: Ok this is actually a way to do it. But you do not need to build a custom solution including Yes/No-Buttons. Just create the `JOptionPane` and place it onto a JDialog instance.

Answer (score 9):

What you need is

```
    final JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane("Hello");
    final JDialog d = pane.createDialog((JFrame)null, "Title");
    d.setLocation(10,10);
    d.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: You can use d.setLocationRelativeTo(someparent); to position it relative to any UI component.

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane(arguments);
pane.setBounds(x, y,width, height);   
pane.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: *"Try this"*  Did *you* try it?  Nothing appears when run in my JRE.

Comment: JOptionPane is a JComponent not a dialog or a window.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Sorry thompson, I did not try. Only checked those 3 lines.

Comment: @Neil Wightman i knew but it has those methods. May be my answer is worng.