# How to use JOptionPane to position your message around the screen

Tags: java, alert, joptionpane

In my code here I am using JOptionPane to create Confirm message boxes.

When they are initiated they always appear at the center of the screen.

Any way to position it in different spots around the screen?

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x;
        x = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do you like bacon?");
        }
    }
```

Comment: The `static` methods of `JOptionPane` are just convince wrappers designed to make your life easier.  You can create an instance of `JOptionPane` and use `createDialog` to get access to it's internal dialog and place it where ever you want

Comment: Very new to Java so I had to look up some other things, but overall your answer makes sense, thanks! :D

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13760117/how-to-set-the-location-of-joptionpane-showmessagedialog.

Comment: Should I mark it as a duplicate?