# How to display message dialogue if guessing number is equal to lucky number?

Tags: java, oop

This code is designed to show message if guess variable is equal to lucky variable which has been initialised. So I have created an object in to read the input from the user. So in the if,else loop I have crafted a condition to see if guess is equal to lucky. My program compiles and when I enter a number, it doesnt show the message dialog.I cannot use println() function and only message dialog to be used

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int guess,lucky;
    String strOut=" ";
    lucky = 8;

     Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("Please guess your lucky number: ");

     guess = in.nextInt();

    if(guess == lucky)
    {
        strOut = "Congratulations! ";
    }
    else
    {
        strOut = "Thank you for guessing! ";
    }

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, strOut);
}
```

}

Comment: put the dialog in your if block

Comment: Code works here; should probably use a different thread for the swing option pane but I can't reproduce the issue with your code.

Comment: so what should I do?

Comment: I'm supposed to display message but I couldn't

Comment: what do you mean "couldn't?

Comment: my guess, it is shown, but outside of your screen (somewhere) since you don't control the position of the dialog

Comment: if that is the issue, this may help you out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13760117/how-to-set-the-location-of-joptionpane-showmessagedialog

Comment: I tried your to run your code and everything works fine

Comment: mine doesnt trigger message that's the problem. Is it the fact that my message dialog is hidden?

Comment: @Big_Smoke that's indeed my guess. The dialog is 'shown', it's just positioned outside of your screen.

Comment: thanks @Stultuske I found it.

Comment: And the rest who managed to help me out.

Comment: so, what was your solution?

Comment: It's hidden in the taskview of my Windows desktop

Answer (score 1):

you should define`JFrame f = new JFrame();`
 and use it in `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f, strOut);`

Comment: What is JFrame ?