# How can i place JOptionPane . showInputDialog to the first position on the screen?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

Let's say I have this code here

```
String s=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Type your age: ");
```

Then I run it, and for some reason the Pane doesn't show up. You need to minimize all windows, and there you'll find it! This doesn't happen always, and I saw it happening also to the tutorial guy, that is supposed to know why...
**So the question is:**

How can I set the showInputDialog so it always comes to the front of the screen?

I reviewed the [Java's API Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) and couldn't find any parameter for the [showInputDialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog-java.lang.Object-) method that would set this (something like JOptionPane.showInputDialog("message", FRONT)). I also saw in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807890/joptionpane-showinputdialog-position) that you can set the location with JDialog, but again, JDialog has a setLocation, that set's only the position (x,y) but not the placement among other windows.

This is a Code where it always happens:

```
public static void main (String [] args){
    Scanner input=new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Choose a form: \nSquare - 1\nCircle - 2\nRectangle - 3");
    int form=input.nextInt();
    switch (form){
    case 1:
        int height=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the height of the square?"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post a complete example which can repro this problem. Whenever I use JOptionPane it ends up at the top of other windows correctly.

Comment: @Codebender, it happens to me just like that... I'm using Eclipse, I wonder if it's a bug...

Comment: @Codebender, I added an example... I'm sorry for the delay!

Comment: It was hidden beneath which application? Some applications will always show on top.

Comment: @user3437460 it always go to the very back, whether I have only Eclipse or I have plenty of windows (firefox, skype, music...)

Comment: It's not a bug -- the console is not playing nice with the GUI here. Make your GUI a pure GUI, not some console/GUI bastardization, and it will work just fine.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels that made it ;)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, can you make it an answer.... I am pretty sure others will face the same problem...:)

Answer (score 2):

you can use `JOptionPane.showInputDialog(rootPane, "Type your age: ");`

change `rootPane` to your parent component.

Comment: this code is works only with a GUI, and cannot use it when a console based program. when i run your example it works fine without any confusion.